# Python - syntax error for no specific reason

Tags: python-2.7

I've been trying to run these blocks of code but it keeps giving me syntax error for no specific reason

```
var1 = 100 
if var1: print "1 - Got a true expression value" 
print var1
else:
print "1 - Got a false expression value"
print var1

var2 = 0 
if var2: print "2 - Got a true expression value" 
print var2
else:
print "2 - Got a false expression value"
print var2

print "Good bye!"
```

Comment: Could you please post the exact error?  Otherwise it's a guessing game for us.

Comment: @tobi , if you find my answer useful ,please marked it !

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your indentation probably.
Here is the indentation code -

```
     var1 = 100 
     if var1:
        print "1 - Got a true expression value" 
        print var1 
     else:
        print "1 - Got a false expression value"
        print var1

     var2 = 0 
     if var2:
        print "2 - Got a true expression value" 
        print var2 
     else:
        print "2 - Got a false expression value"
        print var2

     print "Good bye!"
```

## Output:

```
   1 - Got a true expression value
   100
   2 - Got a false expression value
   0
   Good bye!
```

[Refer here](http://ideone.com/tcKhZv)